# Angular directive: passing scope objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I got a directive which has a model passed by an attribute:

use strict;

```
angular.module('ebs-front')
.directive('ebsIa', function() {
    return{
        restrict: 'A'.
        scope: {
            opened: '=ebsIaOpened',
            model: '=ebsIaModel',
            cb: '&ebsIaCb'
        },
        controller: function($scope, $uibModal){
            console.log('check');
            $scope.text = { text: 'test'};
            $scope.$watch('opened', function(newValue) {
                if(newValue === true){
                    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({ 
                        controller: 'ImpactAnalyseController',
                        templateUrl: 'common/directive/ebs-ia-template.html'                
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }   
});
```

In this directive, I need to do some operations and then open a modal window. So for so good, but the thing is, I want the $scope.model to be accessible in ImpactAnalysisController as well.

My assumption was that $scope.test and $scope.model will be available in ImpactAnalysisController automatically, but apparently a isolated scope is created which is only valid for the controller: function part.

What would be a good way to pass the model variable of the scope to the ImpactAnalysisController?! And why isn't it default behaviour in angular?

If I define my directive like below, then the removeFromFilters (in this case) IS available in the directive, so I'm kinda puzzled. Any help would be appreciated...

```
use strict;

angular.module('ebs-front')
.directive('ebsIa', function() {
    return{
        restrict: 'A'.
        scope: {
            opened: '=ebsIaOpened',
            model: '=ebsIaModel',
            cb: '&ebsIaCb'
        },
        controller: 'ImpactAnalysisController'
        };          
)};
```

Comment: do add code instead of screen shots

Comment: The issue you are facing is that you are unable to get values from attributes to your controller..right..?

Comment: Exactly, I'm passing ebsIaModel to the directive with attributes. And I was expecting $scope.model to contain that object inside the ImpactAnalysisController.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to share data between controllers in Angular. A couple that come to mind:

1- Use a $rootScope.broadcast('keyName', value) and listen for the value with $scope.on('keyName', function(){...}  Use with care, not the best approach most of the time

2- Keep the data not in the controller but in a Service or Factory, and inject that into your controllers (preferable)

Comment: Are services singleton by default in angular?

Comment: Yes, services are singletons.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be a good way to pass the model variable of the scope to the ImpactAnalysisController?!

Depends on what the controller has access to and intends to do with it.

> And why isn't it default behaviour in angular?

You're asking the wrong question. You chose an Isolate Scope. Why did you choose an Isolate Scope, if you wanted to inherit properties from its parent?

**What may solve your problem:**

If you're passing a pure model and expect to have some IO where the user is potentially altering the model I recommend reading and implementing: [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

It will make the model and mechanisms to interact with it available to your directive(s) via an injectable Controller, independent of the type of scope you choose. All you have to do is require 'ngModel' according to [$compile documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

Comment: Maybe true, but in the 2nd code block the model variable of the directive is accessible in ImpactAnalysisController. It looks like because of the controller: function($scope, $uibModal){ a scope is created which is online valide **inside** the function. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: The $scope that goes into the controller is not created there, rather injected from the context. I have no idea how your $uibModal is written to behave, so I can't comment objectively about how to make it do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with uibmodal's resolve functionality:

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    })
```

Item is passed from the parent scope to the ModalInstanceCtrl and becomes available in the controller as variable. Exactly was I was looking for!